# Json serializing and deserializing

Tags: python, deep-diff

I am comparing two nested dictionaries using deepdiff package in python. I want to store it in a file but it's giving me an error

> 'prettyordered set is not json serializable'

I tried it converting using `'to_dict'`, same error. I also tried to convert it using `'to_json'`, it solves the problem but it adds backslash in the keys and values and also while reading I am not able to read, it gives me an error :

> 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError'

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
import json

variable1={'key':'key32','hello':'hello1'}
variable2={"key3":'key','hello':'hello2'}
result=DeepDiff(variable1,variable2)
result=result.to_json()
print(result)

filename='json_serializable'+'.txt'
objects_file = 'D:\\'+ filename
f = open(objects_file,'w')
f.write(json.dumps(result))

with open('D:\\Registryvalues\\'+filename) as json_file:
    variable1 = json.load(json_file)
print(variable1)
```

I want to write and read that difference object that I am getting using deepdiff. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Looks like you are reading another file, not the one you create?

Comment: No it's right .     Here, I wrote wrong by mistake

Comment: Also, you don't close the file you write.

Comment: I did that also , still same problem.

Comment: How did you solve it?